# How do I edit a complex config file with tabs and curly brackets using Python?

Tags: python, regex, config

I have a config file that looks like this:

```
#  EAP types NOT listed here may be supported via the "eap2" module.
#  See experimental.conf for documentation.
#
        eap {
                #  Invoke the default supported EAP type when
                #  EAP-Identity response is received.
                #
                #  The incoming EAP messages DO NOT specify which EAP
                #  type they will be using, so it MUST be set here.
                #
                #  For now, only one default EAP type may be used at a time.
                #
                #  If the EAP-Type attribute is set by another module,
                #  then that EAP type takes precedence over the
                #  default type configured here.
                #
                default_eap_type = peap

                #  A list is maintained to correlate EAP-Response
                #  packets with EAP-Request packets.  After a
                #  configurable length of time, entries in the list
                #  expire, and are deleted.
                #
```

I want to be able to edit the value of the default_eap_type option under the eap structure. I can't simply do a substring as default_eap_type appears again in another location in the config file but under a different structure. What is the best way to use Python to change the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if you don't have a parser for the format:

```
output_lines = []
is_eap = False
for line in file:
    if line.strip().startswith('eap {'):
        is_eap = True
    elif line.strip().split()[1] == '{':
        is_eap = False
    if is_eap:
        output_lines.append(process_line(line))
    else:
        output_lines.append(line)
```

This is super rough, but hope it helps.